# Need help to move files from folder to the archive folder within older than 600 days

Tags: file, cmd, move, forfiles

I have multiple directories with older files that I need to move to its archive folder.

Source Directory: A\B\C
Target Directory: A\B\C\archive

But I don't want to target files under Directory D --> A\B\C\D

Comment: Is that really *really* DOS (the ancient command based operating system) or rather the Windows Command Line? They are very differernt.

Comment: Windows command line

Comment: I'd recommend `robocopy /?` then.

Comment: forfiles /p "C:\Users\212595894\Documents" /s /m *.* /d -9 /c "cmd /c move @path C:\Users\212595894\Documents\move"

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. When you are satisfied that the files would be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

=== Move-Over600.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t' |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-600) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\archive' -WhatIf
    }
```

If you must run this from cmd.exe:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Move-Over600.ps1"
```